# Running window AC into the living room or bathroom, for a room without a window?

Tags: hvac

I need to install a window ac unit into a room without a window, so my idea is to vent into either the bathroom or the living room. I can't use the central AC at night (and there is no solution for this). So just accept this is the only solution left.

I can't move, which would solve the problem. I can't cut a large square hole in the wall to install a permanent window unit through the wall, because the outside wall is concrete and I am renting.

A mini split is too expensive and I'm not allowed to drill a hole in the wall anyway.

My room is a difficult room. This room has a sliding glass door which opens on the OUTSIDE, so I cannot just crack open the door to install a window or portable AC unit, or anyone can just walk in.

Here's the unusual sliding door instead of a window, no way to block it. It opens outside along the exterior wall, as shown.

[image]

So the idea is that I install a window unit inside of my interior doorway, and build a door frame to hold the window ac unit, so the door will open and close like a normal door. Or, I can just buy another same door for $50 and cut a hole in it to mount the AC unit.

The problem, then, comes with which room to vent it to, and how to do it.

If I vent into my bathroom, it will be easier to drain the ac directly into my sink, and I can leave on the vent fan all night to vent the heat and humidity. If needed I can also run a dehumidifier.

[image: bathroom door location]

If I vent into the living room, I could also install another window unit in the living room to vent the hot air from my room outside. I could also open both doors in the living room every morning to vent out the living room. And then run a tube from the window ac drain port across my room into my bathroom.

[image: living room door location]

Here is my layout, and my two proposed locations, in blue and purple:

[image: layout]

As shown with the cubic feet, the living room is nearly 4 times larger than the bedroom. So, I'm thinking that may be the best solution.

Which door is a better location, and will this work?

Comment: The problem isn't (primarily) the condensate drain, it is the **heat**. For every drop of "cold" you put in your bedroom, you will add a corresponding drop of "hot" to another room. Unless you vent through one of the other windows. Have you considered something like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Whynter-14-000-BTU-Dual-Hose-Portable-Air-Conditioner-in-10-000-SACC-DOE-in-White-with-HEPA-and-Activated-Carbon-Filter-ARC-147WF/318926912#overlay)? The basic idea is you have a "window air conditioner" but instead of it sitting in a window where it can get air in, add heat from your room to

Comment: the air (making your room cooler) and send the now-hot air out the window, instead if has connections for two pieces of ductwork which you run across to the actual window. May be hard to find one that can handle a 28' duct run, but that is essentially what you need - otherwise you're going to heat the rest of the apartment when cooling your bedroom.

Comment: I'm ok with heating the rest of the apartment during the 8 hours of night, then cooling it in the morning by opening the doors for air flow and using the central AC. I'm ok with increased electric costs. And I can mitigate it by putting another window AC unit over there in the living room window.

Comment: Option #3, bedroom exterior slider, hung in a piece of plywood and using blocking to secure the door.

Comment: As I mentioned, the sliding door opens on the OUTSIDE, there is no way to block it. It opens outside the house. When it's open, it opens along the outside wall. The opening is doorway sized.

Comment: A bit unusual. But of course, when renting in a situation where you can't (as common, and as stated) make any holes in the walls *and* you aren't paying the power bill (you actually haven't said whether you are or not) so you're not paying double/triple for the AC (cool, which heats, then cool again...) it can make some strange logical sense. **Definitely the living room** - that will give more volume to handle the heat, plus you can have windows open which will help a lot.

Comment: I am paying the power bill and I'm ok if it goes up significantly. Thanks for the tip about the living room, that's the direction I'm leaning too. Yes, the situation is unusual. I would prefer to move, but the world is unusual too right now so I'm stuck here.

Comment: how big is the kitchen window?  You can get some pretty big A/C units that could handle the space, just add some fans to help circulate.  I find that just having one A/C will reduce the humidity combined with a bedroom ceiling fan is enough to sleep comfortably.

Comment: Standard window size. Not big. A window AC unit won't be able to cool the living room and my room from the far corner. Also, I need my bedroom door closed at night.

Comment: I'm confused as to how you're going to install an AC unit in the doorway but still be able to close the door. TBH, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Ultimately, the decision is yours. You ask which location is better, but don't define what "better" really means to _you_. To us, venting the heat into the living space just sounds like a bad idea, but you seem determined to do it, so do it. If you manage to build a frame to put the AC in a doorway, make it mobile so you can move it from bathroom to living room and determine with experience which works best for you.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm going to build a door out of 2x4 and mount the 2x4+plywood door onto the door hinges just like a normal door. The door will open. I will add horizontal crossbeam and mount the AC unit at the top of the door, and then like a gate put another diagonal crossbeam for rigidity. The plywood sides will add further rigidity. I've had a lot of time to think about this. This is the best idea I came up with.

Comment: For $50 I could actually buy the same hollow door and then I can cut a hole for the ac unit, but the 2x4 method will be cheaper. But I still might just get a replacement door I can dispose of when I move out, but it's beside the point. Either way, it's not hard to mount an AC unit in a door in a way that's non-destructive to the place I'm renting.

Comment: Are there no windows a 2 hose portable ac unit can use? As the house heats up the efficiency will drop.

Comment: @EdBeal See the layout, you will see the only window in the entire place in the farthest corner of the living room.

Comment: It's not your question, but contemplate better ideas than having an A/C swinging on hinges on a makeshift door!   How about putting the A/C on small casters, and attaching a door-sized piece of hard foam insulation?  Then you just wheel the thing into the doorway at night.  Or, heavy plastic sheeting with velcro to attach it to the door frame.

Comment: @jay613 I hadn't thought of that. Good idea! Downside is how do I make the thing stay up. If I cut a hole in the door (a replacement door of the same door), then it holds itself up.

Comment: LOL a chain of A/C's would actually work.  Dreadfully inefficient, but it would work.  Are you in a place with plenty of water like the Mississippi, Canada, Danube, Thailand, etc.? You could always a have a system that rejects heat *into the water* and then dumps it down the drain. Marine A/C units work like that, they reject heat into service water, which is seawater typically.  Water's ability to absorb heat is phenomenal, the best of any substance. In fact 1 BTU *is defined as* the heat required to raise 1 pound of water 1 degree F.

Comment: I'm in a place that is somewhat subtropical, and somewhat rainy, although mostly sunny. I'm not sure what you mean by converting heat into water.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134361/discussion-between-diy-user-and-mazura).

Answer (score 1):

I'll regard this as one of those (similar) situations where the room to be cooled is deep in the interior of a building, with no outside surfaces. That will avoid a lot of questions about where and how to install A/Cs.

The A/C has to be able to get heat to the outdoors or neither of your solutions will work.  Over the course of eight hours, the living room cannot absorb and retain all the heat that the A/C will produce.  It's not big enough.  The heat has to go outside.

The bathroom idea might work well if the exhaust fan works, and if there is a way for fresh (outside) air to get INTO the bathroom.  From your plan drawings it looks like the only opening is into the bedroom being cooled, so that really can't work.   On the other hand if you could create air flow through the closet towards the kitchen, and open the kitchen window a little, the bathroom fan would draw in outside air from the kitchen window.  If the exhaust fan is of sufficient size, and functioning well, that MIGHT be the better approach (of the two you propose) to removing heat from the bedroom and to the outside.  The bathroom will hopefully remain 5 to 15 degrees above outside temperature all night, as its fan draws outside air through it.

The living room way might work.  I think you'll have to experiment.  Say it's 90F outside and also in the living room.  Say you cool your bedroom to 75F.  The temperature of the living room will start to rise, and once it gets above 95F or so the air conditioner's efficiency will reduce, and the effect of heating the living room will accelerate.    This will eventually reach an equilibrium. The question is, where will that be?   Will it be where your bedroom is 75, the living room is 100, and the kitchen window is expelling heat as fast as the A/C is producing it?   Or will be be where your bedroom is 90 (producing nothing useful for you), the living room is 115?  Is there any temperature, at least 1 degree below the outside temperature, where the kitchen window will remove heat as fast as it's being produced?  Or will the living room temperature keep rising until the A/C fails completely?

I think the only way to find out is to try it.  I think the equilibrium state will happen within an hour or two.

It's possible that putting a second A/C in the kitchen window will expel heat faster than if you just leave it open.   That's worth trying if you have a second A/C.   It's also possible that putting the largest A/C you can squeeze into the kitchen window and leaving the bedroom door open will, on the whole, produce the best cooling effect, even if it's not that great.

Comment: Closet only opens into the room, it's a walk-in closet. It doesn't open into bathroom or living room.

Comment: Closet only opens into the room, it's a walk-in closet. It doesn't open into bathroom or living room. House will be 69 degrees at night right before bed. Then, the bedroom needs to maintain 69 degrees for 8 hours at night. During summer, it could get to 70s/80s during the night in summer. It's 60s at night this time of year ("winter"). It will never have to cool from 90s/100s. It doesn't get that hot at night here.

Comment: I think you're right when you say I'll need to experiment. Just hoping for any more tips before I move forward. This did help because now I know I need two window units, not one. One of them has to go in the living room window.

Comment: You need 2 outside sources for the A/C in the living room, one for fresh air in, another for heated air out.  Unless the window can fit a fan in the bottom and remain open on the top, it won't get any fresh air.  Even then you will get recirculated air with the screen.  If you just blow air in via the kitchen, the bathroom vent becomes the out and the cold air just goes right out.

Comment: DIY using that window would be better than pumping hot air into the home, where are you located that doesn’t require windows for escape?

Comment: @EdBeal The bedroom and living area both have 2 doors, I don't think it needs windows for escape.

Comment: @EdBeal It's a sliding glass door instead of a window. That's the egress for code.

Comment: So you want 69 when it's "80s" outside ... that's different from my (arbitrary) illustration but I think the conclusion is the same .... it CAN work, if you find a way to dump heat from the living room to outside fast enough to keep up with the heat being produced by the bedroom A/C.  I think if it doesn't get as hot out as in my illustration, you are quite likely to find a way ... I just can't predict exactly what you'll need to do.

Comment: I used 90 in my illustration intentionally, because window A/Cs become less efficient above 95.  If you can find that "equilibrium" while keeping your LR well below 95, this might come together.

Comment: So basically I should get the two AC units, install one in the bedroom doorway to the living room and one in the living room window, and see what happens. If it gets too hot, I will have to find a way to pump more heat out of the living room faster. Really I would need a window unit for the living room window rated for the total footage of my room and the living room combined, with additional allowance for the heat generated by the door/window ac from my room.

Comment: Exactly that.   You could also set your central A/C to 95 as an escape hatch to keep things from spiraling .. unless the thermostat is in the bedroom.

Comment: @jay613 Brilliant, very good. Good escape hatch to prevent from getting too hot in the living room by setting central air to 95 as a last resort. Exactly the type of suggestions I'm looking for and why I posted this question!

Comment: So if I put a 150sqft ac for my room, and then a 600+ (or maybe 1,000) sqft ac in the living room window, that should probably be enough.